# Receiving a #1062 duplicate error in mySQL/phpMyAdmin despite not having a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, key

I currently have a database called `Spreadsheet` with 2291 rows, each with 6 columns.

I also have a .csv file with 1000 more of these rows with the same 6 columns, though three of them are set default to `NULL` (same as some of the data in my database, meaning, some are set to NULL as default too). I was trying to import them (not `replace`) into the existing database.

The first columns is the `primary key`, and I know both the .csv and database do not have duplicate primary keys. The primary key looks something like this: `0015000000b0Y2u`

My question is: how do I import these 1000 more rows (which come with unique `primary keys` themselves) into the pre-existing 2291 rows without getting the #1062 error?

```
SQL query:

INSERT INTO  `Spreadsheet` (  `accountID` ,  `accountName` ,  `website` ,  `rating` ,  `imageURL` ,  `comments` ,  `category` ) 
VALUES (

'0015000000b0Y3z',  'Kittredge and Associates Inc',  'kittredgeandassociates.com', NULL ,  'kittredgeandassociates.com.jpg', NULL , NULL
)
MySQL said: 

#1062 - Duplicate entry '0015000000b0Y3z' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Attached above is the #1062 error I have been receiving, despite being 100% sure that I do not have a duplicate key for `PRIMARY`.

I do not want to have mySQL autoincrement, as I have looked into that, and it is not the solution I am looking for.

I have tried changing the duplicate entry offender key, but to no avail, same error. Could someone lend me a hand?

Comment: I don't understand why you say you're 100% certain that you don't have a duplicate key, then say you tried changing the *duplicate entry offender key*? Have you searched your `.csv` file for this key and only found one result? If you're 100% certain on your cat's grave that there is no duplicate, you can drop the primary key and you won't get the error.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to clear the table before you tried to import the file again?

Comment: @njk I altered the suspected offender key to another value to test if it will work. It did not. What do you mean by dropping the primary key?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage A primary key is a way for a record to be uniquely identified on a table. When you drop the primary key, the constraint is dropped and thus allows you to insert a duplicate record. This shouldn't be the solution, however.

Comment: @devOp What do you mean by clearing the table?

Comment: @njk Thanks. I am confident we can find a solution where we don't have to drop my existing primary keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that your primary key is a character column with a case insensitive collation (e.g. `latin1_swedish_ci`).  If so, lower case and upper case letters are considered to be "equal", which would lead to a duplicate.

Here's a demonstration. Note the difference in the value of collation_name:

```
CREATE TABLE t3 (mycol VARCHAR(4) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES ('A'),('a');

-- Error Code: 1062
-- Duplicate entry 'a' for key 'PRIMARY'

CREATE TABLE t4 (mycol VARCHAR(4) COLLATE latin1_bin PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO t4 VALUES ('A'),('a');

-- 2 row(s) affected
```

---

If you need MySQL to consider uppercase and lowercase letters to be unequal, then you need to specify  either a case sensitive or a binary collation, rather than a case insensitive collation, for that column.

(NOTE: MySQL names collations that are case insensitive with a `_ci` on the end of the collation name, e.g. `latin1_swedish_ci`.)

If the column is currently `latin1` characterset and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation, you probably want to change the collation on the column to be either `latin1_general_cs` or `latin1_bin`.

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE t3 CHANGE mycol mycol VARCHAR(4) COLLATE latin1_general_cs ;
```

---

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-collation.html

Comment: Ah. This makes sense. The collation is indeed `latin1_swedish_ci`

Do you recommend changing my primary key column to `latin1_bin`?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: If you need to consider the values `'1c'` and `'1C'` to be unequal, then yes, you need to specify a case sensitive or a binary collation. (Answer updated.)

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: is it possible that your earlier attempts to "import" the new data to the table already added some of the rows, and that the "#1062 Duplicate entry" exception is caused by an attempt to re-insert a row that was already (previously) inserted?

Comment: An `INSERT IGNORE` statement would handle any errors as warnings, and would allow the new rows to be inserted.  Or, a `REPLACE` statement would delete the existing row, and then insert the new one.  (You would certainly want to create a backup copy of the table before you do a REPLACE.) The other alternative, to debug the issue,  is to create a new table WITHOUT the unique constraint, insert all of the existing rows from the current table, and then insert the new rows. Then you would have all of the rows, including any "duplicate" rows, which you could then find using SQL.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593 I plan on doing a full replace.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would get this error if you are correct that the PK and any other unique indexes are not being violated.  A solution might be to use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or the [IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) keyword.